# How expo-updates works in different versions of a react native bare workflow app?

Tags: react-native, expo, version, over-the-air

I am using `expo-updates` to update my react-native `bare workflow` app over-the-air. I have a question when I publish my app with different versions.

Lets say my app version is 1.0.0 and build number is 1, and I publish my app to play/app store.

Users will download my app with version 1.0.0, build number 1.

Then I can do an over-the-air update and no problem, all the users will get the update.

Then I am publishing another version of my app (2.0.0), build number 2.

Now some users will be have version 1.0.0, build 1 and some will have 2.0.0, build 2.

Now If I do an over-the-air update,

1. Will this over-the-air update be applied to all the users ? (users who have 1.0.0, build 1 and 2.0.0, build 2)
2. Or will this over-the-air update only applied to the user who downloaded latest version of the app ? (i.e. 2.0.0, build 2)

If the answer is scenario 1,

What will happen in my version 2.0.0, build 2, I have some file changes that do not update with over-the-air (eg: build.gradle, AndroidManifest.xml, etc), In that case users who have old version (1.0.0 build 1) , is there a chance that their app is not getting work ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer and it is to have [release channels](https://docs.expo.dev/distribution/release-channels/). When you configured a `release-channel` for a particular build and do an over-the-air update with that release channel, only the builds with the particular release-channel get updated.